# Looking for an effective way to calculate affinity matrix

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Well, suppose that I have an image with dimensions n by n. which is ordered lexicographically on a column vector with dimensions n^2 by 1.

I want to calculate following affinity matrix for image:

[image]

Clearly, the matrix is symmetric and we can reduce the calculations using this property, this is my attempt to implement the above matrix calculation:

```
def w(R,sigma,x):
    n=x.shape[0]
    w=np.zeros_like(x).astype(np.float64)
    img=x.ravel()
    for i in range(img.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img.shape[0]):
            if(max(abs(i//n-j//n),abs(i%n-j%n))>R or i==j):
                w[i//n,j%n]=0
                continue
            w[i//n,j%n] = np.exp((-1*(int(img[i])-int(img[j]))**2)/sigma)
    return w
```

where R is the threshold for norm, sigma is the exponential damper and x is the image.

However, this code is very ineffective, and its order is n^2, do you have any better idea for implementing the code faster?

Comment: Is the result of your current implementation correct? It can only work on the square array.

Comment: @MechanicPig I stated in my question that suppose my image is square array.

Comment: I mean, your implementation seems to be inconsistent with the formula description. For an n * n matrix, it seems that the generated affinity matrix should be an n^2 * n^2 matrix, while yours only generates an n * n matrix.